# illegal string body character after dollar sign

Tags: groovy

if i define a groovy variable

```
def x = "anish$"
```

it will throw me error, the fix is

```
def x = "anish\$"
```

apart form "$" what are the blacklist characters that needs to be backslash,Is there a Groovy reference that lists the reserved characters. Most “language specifications”  mention these details, but I don’t see it in the Groovy language [spec](http://groovy.codehaus.org/jsr/spec/) (many “TODO” comments).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just use single quotes:

```
def x = 'anish$'
```

If this isn't possible, the only thing that's going to cause you problems is `$`, as that is the templating char used by `GString` (see the GString section [on this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString) -- about half way down)

Obviously, the backslash char needs escaping as well, ie:

```
def x = 'anish\\'
```

Comment: so the only reserved word is $

Comment: It's used as a token for templating, so if you are using `"` (indicating you want to use templating) then yes, `$` would need escaping...  If you use single quotes `'` you don't need to escape it

Comment: As in java, backslashes need escaping as they are the escape character...  Updated my answer

Comment: so how i can define in variable backslash, is this not possible at all

Answer (score 12):

You can use octal representation. the character **$** represents **044** in octal, then:

`def x = 'anish\044'`

or

`def x = 'anish\044'`

For example, in Java i did use like this:

`def x = 'anish\044'`

If you wants knows others letters or symbols converters, [click here](https://munc.com/jseffects/asciiConverter.html) :)

Comment: I prefer this solution because I use traditional java code within a groovy script. I can copy and paste code from my java files in Eclipse to a groovy script without worrying about any differences between Java syntax and groovy syntax.

Answer (score 4):

The solution from *tim_yates* does not work in some contexts, e.g. in a Jasper report.
So if still everything with a `$` sign wants to be interpreted as some variable (`${varX}`), e.g. in

```
"xyz".replaceAll("^(.{4}).{3}.+$", "$1...")
```

then simply make the dollar sign a **single concatenated character `'$'`**, e.g.

```
"xyz".replaceAll("^(.{4}).{3}.+"+'$', '$'+"1...")
```

Comment: you even can't use `'xy'` in a Groovy Jasper expression cause it wants to have the double quotes there

Answer (score 3):

It might be a cheap method, but the following works for me.

```
def x = "anish" + '$'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative that is useful in Groovy templating is `${'$'}`, like:

```
def x = "anish${'$'}" // anish$
```

Interpolate the Java String `'$'` into your GString.